# Fastlane Gym - multiple export options

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

We're having several builds that use different app IDs, provisioning profiles, and teams (one team ID is official, other is enterprise). I'm trying to bring this together in the Gymfile since fastlane can't figure out the profiles. How does the Gymfile format has to be to support multiple build methods and profiles?

This fails, always taking the last entry (app-store) ...

```
output_directory "./fastlane/builds"

export_options(
  method: "enterprise",
  provisioningProfiles: { 
    "com.company.app.enterprise.production": "Our_App_Enterprise_PRD",
    "com.company.app..enterprise.staging": "Our_App_Enterprise_STG"
  },
  method: "development",
  provisioningProfiles: { 
    "com.company.app..production": "Our_App_Official_PRD",
    "com.company.app..staging": "Our_App_Official_STG"
  },
  method: "app-store",
  provisioningProfiles: { 
    "com.company.app": "Our_App_Official_AppStore"
  }
)
```

This fails, too. Always taking the first entry ...

```
output_directory "./fastlane/builds"

export_options(
  method: "enterprise",
  provisioningProfiles: { 
    "com.company.app.enterprise.production": "Our_App_Enterprise_PRD",
    "com.company.app..enterprise.staging": "Our_App_Enterprise_STG"
  }
)

export_options(
  method: "development",
  provisioningProfiles: { 
    "com.company.app..production": "Our_App_Official_PRD",
    "com.company.app..staging": "Our_App_Official_STG"
  }
)

export_options(
  method: "app-store",
  provisioningProfiles: { 
    "com.company.app": "Our_App_Official_AppStore"
  }
)
```

Comment: I don't use Gymfiles, but I would assume that you can only put one `export_options` Hash at a time. Have you considered just calling `gym` three times with the different options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have multiple `export_options` in one `Gymfile`, instead you'll have to call *match* multiple times from within your `Fastfile`, with different `export_options` each time.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I solved this slightly different  by having only one `export_options` in the Gymfile with all necessary `provisioningProfiles` assignments and then define the `export_method` in the gym params in each of the lanes in the Fastfile. Works for me. :)

Comment: Hi @BadmintonCat Did you have to create multiple lanes gym in the Fastfile? And how did you handle the team_id or itc?

Comment: I love it when the inventor of fastlane answers your question on SO..

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not using the GymFile, the better way is to use something like this in your fastfile:
`export_options: "fastlane/AppStoreExportOptions.plist",`

To create the correct plist, have a look at this great article: https://blog.bitrise.io/new-export-options-plist-in-xcode-9

Follow the Xcode 9 settings.